# Parsing data from a local .wsdl file under Android

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

Is it possible to parse data from a .wsdl file under android? I've been trying to use ksoap2 library but can't find a way to make it parse data from a .wsdl local file rather than calling a webservice.

Answer (score -1):

Here basic android tutorial to access web service in android [basic ksoap android tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html)

For parse the data from webservice you need to

1) Call webservice for that I already give a link

2) and pasted sample code to parse data getting from .wsdl i.s webservice

```
 SoapObject obj2=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; 

for(int i=0; i<obj2.getPropertyCount(); i++)
{
   SoapObject obj3 =(SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(0);
   int id= Integer.parseInt(obj2.getProperty(0).toString());
   String name = obj2.getProperty(1).toString();
   String lastNmae = obj2.getProperty(2).toString();
   int mobNo= Integer.parseInt(obj2.getProperty(3).toString());
}
```

If still have problem then you can write me.
and give the code you written( if possible )so that I can help you.

Comment: He asked for parsing from local file, not from response of web service.